# Application's Service Principal added to a Group within User Assignment receiving AADSTS50105 error

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

Using Azure Active Director PowerShell, I added an Application's Service Principal to an Azure Active Directory Group.  This group was then added to User Assignment.  When users attempt to access this Application via the User Assignment, they receive the following error:

AADSTS50105: Application 'D246xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx35926B' 
is not assigned to a role for the application '85cdxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxb879eb'

Is this possible?  I know that if I add the Application's Service Principal directly to the User Assignment, it works.  It just will not work for the Application's Service Principal if it is assigned via a Group.

Comment: So wait? Are you trying to assign a user role to a service principal? Couldn't you mark the appRole with an allowed member type of "Application" and create an appRoleAssignment to give the app permission to the service principal? Or is that what you are already doing but trying to do it via a group?

Comment: It's impossible. Oauth2.0 permission doesn't support to assign to the app, if you add service principal to a group, it cannot inherit Oauth2.0 permission.